# jQuery : Sum multiple select value if only selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I sum the value of selected multiple item if only the item is selected. From the example I wanna get the value of "X12SO+X13SO=30"

```js
let sum = 0;
$("select[name='myselect[]'] option").each(function(){
  sum += +this.value.split("|")[1];
});
$("input[name='myresult']").val(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select multiple class="form-control" id="multipleSelect" name="myselect[]">
<option value="X12SO|10">X12SO</option>
<option value="X13SO|20">X13SO</option>
<option value="X14SO|30">X14SO</option>
<option value="X15SO|40">X15SO</option>
<option value="X16SO|50">X16SO</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="myresult">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onchange` to detect if the selected options changed.

```js
let sum = 0;
$("#multipleSelect").on("change", function(){
  sum = 0;
  // if there are no options being selected, it would be an empty array[]
  // and sum each splited value
  ($(this).val() || []).map(v=>sum += +v.split("|")[1])
  $("input").val(sum);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select multiple class="form-control" id="multipleSelect" name="myselect[]">
<option value="X12SO|10">X12SO</option>
<option value="X13SO|20">X13SO</option>
<option value="X14SO|30">X14SO</option>
<option value="X15SO|40">X15SO</option>
<option value="X16SO|50">X16SO</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="myresult">
```

Comment: @Hikarunmemory, what is v in map

Comment: @whoami, each value of the selected options. If you select `X12SO`, `v` would be `X12SO|10`.