# Trying to Add selected items's values from Multiple Select Drop-down

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have Multiple Select Drop-down tag. But i failed to add the value of each item is selected.
[This is the Sample Output of Multiple Select Drop-Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SblDM.jpg)
I tried this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832479/jquery-sum-multiple-select-value-if-only-selected)

It's the form code as i am working on Laravel

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('laboratoryReceptController.store') }}">
                            @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="labTestName" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Laboratary Test') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">                                                                                                                                                 
                                    <select multiple="multiple" id="labTestName" name="labTest[]" class="form-control labTestName @error('labTestName') is-invalid @enderror" data-dependent="price">
                                        <option value="">Select Test Name</option>
                                            @foreach ($lab as $item)
                                                <option value="{{ $item->TestPrice }}">{{ $item->TestName }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    @error('labTestName')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>                              
                            </div>                                                    

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="price" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Test Fee') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="price" type="text" class="form-control price @error('price') is-invalid @enderror" name="price" required readonly>

                                @error('price')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="patient" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Patient Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="patient" type="text" class="form-control" name="patient" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="number" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Patient Number') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="number" type="text" class="form-control" name="number">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="date" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Date') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="date" type="date" class="form-control" name="date">
                            </div>
                        </div>                                           
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Save Records') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Its the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
let sum = 0;
$('#labTestName').on('change',function(){
    sum = 0;

    ($("#labTestValue option:selected").val() || []).map(v=>sum += +v.split("|")[1])           
    document.getElementById('price').value=sum;
});});
    </script>
```

When i tried this its just shows 0 in price textField. Please also let me know why the drop-down GUI is not good
[its the output of Multiple Drop-Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNsWx.jpg)

Comment: Hello friend, @jitendra-yadav will you please help me to get solve this problem? waiting for your precious response thanks

Comment: maybe you need to parse the value to int before doing the calculation.

Comment: i had tried it but it doesn't work @charitra-shrestha

Comment: Hello, @Dai will you plz help me why i am getting all time zero

Comment: Is it working well. Provide the upvote plz when you are capable for up voting. Welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you bro.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="selmultiple" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<button id="btn" onclick="add()">Click to get sum</button>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
 function add() {
 var sum = 0;
 var values = $('#selmultiple').val();
 values.forEach(function(val){
//try to parse the value that you get from the select tag.
 sum = parseInt(val) + sum;
});
console.log(sum);
}
</script> 
</html>
```

Try to analyze the code by running snippet